# How to get the yahoo finance csv directly into python

Tags: python, csv, yahoo-finance

Does anybody know how to get yahoo finance csv directly into python?

The problem is that when i try to get the data with this (example) link:

```
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WU&a=4&b=20&c=2015&d=05&e=21&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv'
```

It gives a pop-up asking if i want to download the csv-file. This causes it to bugg when i try to read it in to python. My scripts is:

```
today = datetime.date.today()

def get_url(stock='GOOG', START_date = str(int(str(today).split('-')[0])-1)+
            '-' +str(int(str(today).split('-')[1])-1) + ('-') +
            str(int(str(today).split('-')[2])-1), END_date= str(today)):
    baseurl = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?'
    stock = 's=WU'

    FROM_date = ('&a=' + START_date.split('-')[1] + '&b=' +
    START_date.split('-')[2] + '&c=' +
    START_date.split('-')[0])

    TO_date = ('&d=' + END_date.split('-')[1] + '&e=' +
    END_date.split('-')[2] + '&f=' + END_date.split('-')[0])

    url = baseurl + stock + FROM_date + TO_date + '&g=d&ignore=.csv'
    return url

rawdate = []
with open(get_url()) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
    for row in reader:
        rawdata.append(row)
```

If i download the csv first i can read it into python, but I want to get to access the csv file directly without having to download it first. Is this possible? alternatively have the csv as temp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use pandas. Here is a [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance).

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
f.ix['2010-01-04']
```

Out[6]: 
Open         1.017000e+01

High         1.028000e+01

Low          1.005000e+01

Close        1.028000e+01

Volume       6.085580e+07

Adj Close    8.755953e+00
Name: 2010-01-04 00:00:00, dtype: float64

Comment: but just out of curiosity is there a way to bypass the "open / save / close" window that pops-up?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
in this file "C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/symbols/tickers.txt"
you have the following tickers
ibm
sbux
msft
"""

import urllib
import re
import json

symbolslist = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/tickers.txt").read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

for symbol in symbolslist:
    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "w+")
    myfile.close()

    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/"+ symbol+ ":US")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    datapoints = data["data_values"]

    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "a")
    for point in datapoints:
        myfile.write(str(symbol+","+str(point[0])+","+str(point[1])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

That should give you what you want.